# react js override webpack config for javascript & css bundle with craco

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, craco, react-app-rewired

i have a react application for which i want to modify the javascript and css bundles

which are building by the webpack every time
the App is build to avoid the browser caching issue
for example right now it is like that

```
chunkFilename: 'static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.css'
```

i want to modify it to

```
chunkFilename: 'static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].' + Date.now().toString() + '.chunk.css'
```

for this i have to  modify webpack default config

but   also dont want to `eject` in my app thats why i am thinking of using `craco` for that

the same way i need to modify `JavaScript bundles`

```
chunkFilename: isEnvProduction
                ? 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.' + Date.now().toString() + '.js'
                : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/[name].chunk.js'
```

how can i do that , i could not find any documentation regarding this